# epoch to datetime format

Tags: python, datetime

```
import psutil
p = psutil.Process(7055)
>>> p.create_time
1267551141.5019531
```

how to convert this time into datetime object so that I can find diff between this time and todays time (current_time = datetime.datetime.today) in mins ?

Comment: `datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(p.create_time)` - but isn't it in the [documentation](https://code.google.com/p/psutil/wiki/Documentation)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't need a datetime to get that.  `time.time` offers the current time, in expressed in seconds since the epoch.  Divide that by 60 to get minutes elapsed:

```
>>> import time
>>> (time.time() - psutil.Process(1).create_time) / 60   
20957.253114116193
```